# How do you remove x-axis labels from a highchart.js bar chart

Tags: plot, highcharts, label, axis-labels

I'm using highcharts.js to build a bar plot. I cannot figure out how to remove the x-axis labels? I know I have to alter the xAxis object but I've tried all the options below and nothing has worked for me. I know this is possible but I'm missing something. Any help is greatly appreciated. Here is the fiddle with the plot I started with [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/osevj9m3/2/).

```
xAxis: {
    categories: [''],
    title: {
        text: null
    },
    labels: {
     enabled:false
    }
}

xAxis: {
    labels: {
     enabled:false
    }
}
```

data object, only a sample size..

```
var obj = {
    "data": [0.397851,1721745],
    "color":'rgb(51, 204, 51)',
    "organism_labels":"klebsiella_oxytoca"
},{
    "data": [0.609935,66529],
    "color":'rgb(51, 204, 51)',
    "organism_labels":"staphylococcus_aureus"
},{
    "data": [0.505084,45563],
    "color":'rgb(51, 204, 51)',
    "organism_labels":"legionella_longbeachae"
},{
    "data": [0.669884,83471],
    "color":'rgba(223, 83, 83, .5)',
    "organism_labels":"enterobacter_aerogenes"
}, {
    "data": [0.688673,1309077],
    "color":'rgba(223, 83, 83, .5)',
    "organism_labels":"pseudomonas_aeruginosa"
}
```

HighCharts.js

```
    /** Histogram **/
    $(function () {
        $('#histogram').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'column',
                zoomType: 'xy'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Histogram'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Please Help!'
            },
            xAxis: {
                min:0,
                max:1,
                minPadding: 0,
                maxPadding: 0
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Reads'
                }
            },
            credits: {
              enabled: false
            },
            series:
                obj
        });
    });
```

Current Plot:

[image: current plot example]

Comment: Have you live demo of your chart? Because xAxis:{labels:{enabled:false}} should work. http://jsfiddle.net/12e95k8s/

Comment: example: http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/osevj9m3/3/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your screenshot, it looks like what you want to remove is the **legend**, not the x-axis labels.

Since each of the items in your `obj` JSON array have their own unique names, the legend will push out each of them unless you set `legend: { enabled: false }` in your chart options (see http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#legend.enabled).

Please let me know if that answers your question.

Comment: wow, can't believe I missed this one. Thanks for helping @brightmatrix

Answer (score 4):

You can try check out the property [visible](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis).

```
  xAxis :{
    visible : false
  }
```

Whether axis, including axis title, line, ticks and labels, should be visible. Defaults to true.